# How to create GCP ElasticSearch Service automated snapshots/backups?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I was under the impression GCP ElasticSearch service comes with automated snapshots/backups. That's what I find in the documentation. It suggests they happen once a day and are stored on storage but I do not see any backups in any of my GCP storage. How do you get access to the automated snapshots?

Try the below command on dev tools

GET _cat/snapshots/cs-automated?v

Output error message:

"type" : "repository_missing_exception",
"reason" : "[cs-automated] missing"

"type" : "repository_missing_exception",
"reason" : "[cs-automated] missing"

"status" : 404

Comment: seems `cs-automated` is not the correct name of repository.
Can you share output of  `GET /_snapshot?pretty`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
GET /_snapshot/found-snapshots
```

Or

```
GET _cat/snapshots/found-snapshots?v
```